# OperationalError at at /users/login/ no such table: auth_user when trying to login on my website

Tags: python, django, railway

I've deployed my website using Railway. I'm pretty sure the error is because I'm switching from sqllite to postgres.

settings.py

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}

if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(
        conn_max_age=500,
        conn_health_checks=True,
    )
```

I've run makemigrations and migrate, but it doesn't fix the error.

**Solution:**
My problem was that I didn't give django my db url

Answer (score -2):

If you encounter the "OperationalError: no such table: auth_user" error in Django, it may indicate that the database tables, including the `auth_user` table used for user authentication, do not exist in the database. This issue often occurs when you switch from one database engine (such as SQLite) to another (such as PostgreSQL) without properly migrating the data.

To resolve this issue and ensure that your database schema is synchronized with your Django project, you can follow these steps:

1. **Backup Your Data (Optional but Recommended):** Before making any changes, it's a good practice to back up your existing data, especially if you have important user information. You can use Django's built-in `dumpdata` management command to export your data to a JSON or XML file.

   ```
   python manage.py dumpdata > data.json
   ```
2. **Remove Existing Database (Optional):** If your PostgreSQL database already contains data that you don't need, you can drop and recreate the database to start with a clean slate.

   ```bash
   dropdb your_database_name
   createdb your_database_name
   ```
3. **Update Database Configuration:** In your `settings.py` file, ensure that the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is set correctly for your PostgreSQL database. It should look something like this:

   ```py
   DATABASES = {
       'default': dj_database_url.config(
           default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
       )
   }
   ```

   Make sure that the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is properly set in your environment. You can check this by running `echo $DATABASE_URL` in your terminal.
4. **Migrate the Database:** Run the following commands to create and apply migrations to your PostgreSQL database:

   ```bash
   python manage.py makemigrations
   python manage.py migrate
   ```

   This will create the necessary database tables, including `auth_user`, in your PostgreSQL database.
5. **Load Data (Optional):** If you backed up your data in step 1, you can now load the data back into the database using the `loaddata` management command:

   ```bash
   python manage.py loaddata data.json
   ```
6. **Test Your Application:** Finally, make sure to thoroughly test your Django application to ensure that everything is working as expected with the new database.
7. **Update the Railway Configuration:** If you are using a hosting platform like Railway, make sure that your environment variables and database settings are correctly configured in the hosting platform's dashboard.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the "no such table: auth_user" error and have your Django application running with PostgreSQL as the database backend. Remember to keep backups of your data to avoid data loss during migration.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a chatgpt response, but the 3rd step is what fixed my problem.